# SFTP Authentication Failed, cannot use sudo, cannot edit hosts file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have used a snapshot on google cloud to create a new instance. My original instance has not been deleted...I don't want it deleted, I just need to access files on a backup from 24 hours ago that were deleted and restore them from the snapshot.

I have followed the guide to setup SSH access using filezilla, however I cannot connect no matter what i try.

I also cannot sudo in google cloud shell "sudo: unable to resolve host"

I cannot edit /etc/hosts file ...wont let me save file even though shell is using root@....

I try to navigate to /etc/hosts and then enter "sudo mv hosts hosts_bak" and get an error saying "operation not permitted.

All I want to do is copy /home/user/public_html/wordpress directory to my local windows PC desktop but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

did you manage to recover your files? To be honest I think your easiest solution here wouldbe to create a new instance from scratch with a fully working system and them mount the snapshot to that instance as an additional disk. This would let you access and recover all your files without bumping into any of the errors you were getting.